# SwiftUI: Aligning in regards to leading edge when using .position()

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm need to set an absolute position for my view.
A `position` modifier is positioning a view in regards to it `center` but I'd like to align it in regards to its `leading edge`.

Is there any way to achieve that?
I was trying to play with `alignmentGuide` but had no luck with that.

Here's my sample code:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Text("Hello, this is a long text.")
            .border(Color.blue, width: 1)
            .position(x: 10, y: 50)

    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
}
```

Red dashed line is showing how I want the text to be positioned.
[image]

Comment: Let's forget about .position for a moment... what do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `GeometryReader` to the `Text`'s background to read out the correct width and then add half of it to the x position.

Just add some variable to safe the width:

```
@State private var textWidth: CGFloat?
```

And then apply the `rectReader` to the `Text`'s background and add the `Text`'s width to the x position:

```
Text("Hello, this is a long text.")
    .border(Color.blue, width: 1)
    .background(rectReader())
    .position(x: 10 + (textWidth ?? 0) / 2, y: 50)
```

That's the `rectReader`:

```
private func rectReader() -> some View {
    return GeometryReader { geometry -> AnyView in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textWidth = geometry.size.width
        }
        return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.clear))
    }
}
```

Comment: But the GeometryReader is reading the size of Text's parent so it's won't be correct.

Comment: @msmialko yes you're totally right, the previous answer was just wrong. This approach is going to work (this time I verified it)